# In SSIS script task not getting execute when it is deployed as an single package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-2016, ssis-2016

I have an SSIS package in which I am using script tasks. Sometimes after making changes to this package and deploying it as a single package, I find that the package runs without error but doesn't actually execute the script task. If I deploy the project as a whole - without making any changes to the package the script task perfectly.

In short, if I do a project deployment the script task work as expected but as a package deployment it doesn't work, there are occasions when deploying the project is not possible so this workaround isn't always available.

I am using Vs 2016 and my target deployment version is also SQL server 2016.

I am unable to identify the root cause for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the logging option of the SQL Server Agent Job.

It can be also related to permissions. Executing the SSIS package will use your security context but running it from the agent impersonates the credentials defined in the proxy, and then runs the job step by using that security context.

Try also adding the [event handlers](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/bi-sql-server/ssis-event-handlers-basics/) to know better about the logs.

Comment: it seems like it is not going inside Script task i have already implemented even handlers

Comment: show us what are the messages generated from the event handlers

Comment: i just figuredout once the packge is getting deployed it removes the code from script task i am not sure why this is happing, script task rollback to its orginal state al the variable and code disappeared

Comment: @user3557922 which version you are using ?

Comment: vs 2015 and sql server 2016